# how to debug when process spawns and threads used

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have a dll I am trying to debug.  I attached to the process running the dll under debug mode and have break points in the code.  But the break points are not hit it seems because code in the dll spawns a new process and runs parts of the code in threads.

Is there some way in Microsoft Visual Studio to have the break points in threaded code or spawned code to be activated?

Comment: If the dll spawns a new process, then that's the process you need to attach to.

Comment: I've opened thread window and have switched to various threads but cannot find the thread where the portion of code I am looking for is being accessed.

Comment: After the dll has spawned the new process, use the visual studio debug menu to attach to that process, then see what you can do.